# laptop screen(s)

Tags: laptop, screen, docking

I (finally) installed [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/) on my work laptop. A Lenovo ThinkPad with docking station and multiple screens.

After install I ran `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, got Nvidia drivers and my external screens work as planned.

However, when I started up the laptop at home (no docking) it starts up nicely, but when X get started I only have a black screen.

Any suggestions ho I can get it to work with and without docking station ???